# sql utilizar cursor para realizar una operacion entre dos tablas

Tags: sql, cursor

Me han pedido que crear un trigger el cual realize una actualizacion del campo saldo de la tabla prestamo, el cual se calcula sumando todos los pagos hechos en la columna monto en la tabla pagoPrestamos, asi que debo hacer una actualizacion de todos los prestamos y su saldo a pagar las tablas tienen estas caracteristicas:

```
create table prestamo(
idCuenta int identity(1,1),
cantidadCuotas int not null,
monto decimal(13,2) not null,
saldo decimal(13,2) not null,
constraint pk_idprestamo primary key(idCuenta)

);

insert into prestamo values(60, 500000, 500000),(60, 5000000, 5000000), (60, 600000, 600000),(60, 1000000, 500000)

create table pagoPrestamo(
idPago int identity(1,1),
idCuenta int not null,
monto decimal(13,2) not null,
fecha date not null,
constraint pk_idpago primary key(idPago),
constraint fk_idcuent foreign key (idCuenta) references prestamo(idCuenta) 
);
insert into pagoPrestamo values(2,5000,'03/03/2018'),(4,10000,'04/13/2018'),(6,15000,'02/23/2018'),(8,45000,'04/04/2018'),(1,50000,'06/05/2018')
```

El trigger que he creado es este:

```
create trigger tr_pago_prestamo on pagoPrestamo
after insert
as
Begin

declare @idPrestamo int
declare @prestamoMonto decimal(13,2)
declare @pagoMonto decimal(13,2)
declare @saldo decimal(13,2)

select @pagoMonto =  Sum(monto) from pagoPrestamo where pagoPrestamo.idCuenta = @idPrestamo
select @prestamoMonto =  monto  from prestamo where idCuenta = @idPrestamo
select @saldo = @prestamoMonto - @pagoMonto

declare logica cursor for select prestamo.idCuenta, prestamo.monto,        prestamo.saldo from prestamo inner join pagoPrestamo on prestamo.idCuenta =   pagoPrestamo.idCuenta

open logica


while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
begin
update prestamo set prestamo.saldo = prestamo.monto - @pagoMonto
fetch next from logica into @idPrestamo, @prestamoMonto, @saldo

end
close logica
deallocate logica
end
```

El problema esta cuando ejecuto el trigger me pone el saldo de la cuenta perstamos en null y no se por que. Soy nuevo en el uso de los cursor, mucha gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola, lo primero de todo, por lo que entiendo, no estas seteando la variable @idPrestamo por lo cual te devuelven null. Otro tema, los cursores no estan recomendados en BBDD ya que perjudican la performance, sería mejor que intentases efectuar un update con la suma del campo monto `select SUM(prestamo.monto) - @pagoMonto`. Un saludo

Comment: En cuanto a la perjudicación de la performance de los cursores te dejo un link: [problemas de desempeño en cursores](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/problemas-de-desempeno-de-cursores-en-sql-server/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tip, pero, es una tarea de bd, talvez el profesor no sabe esa info que me has proporciando, cuando lo vea de nuevo, le muestro el link que me facilitaste

Comment: si en la tarea te piden usar cursores, primero verifica que `@idPrestamo` se le asigné un valor y con ello puedas efectuar la obtención de las propiedades que necesitas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas:

- Ya te lo han mencionado, estas haciendo `update prestamo set prestamo.saldo = prestamo.monto - @pagoMonto` sin filtro, es decir estás actualizando todas las filas de la tabla `prestamo`, entiendo que en realidad lo que deberías hacer es:

  ```
  UPDATE prestamo SET prestamo.saldo = prestamo.monto - @pagoMonto
     WHERE idcuenta = @idPrestamo
  ```

  Aunque, el nombre de la variable no es el más adecuado, sería preferible `@idCuenta`
- Otro problema, es que NO estas haciendo un `FETCH` de los valores del cursor al comienzo, es decir la primer vuelta del ciclo del curso `@idPrestamo` va a ser `NULL`. El esqueleto de un ciclo de cursor es:

  ```
  open cursor
  fetch variables
  while
     logica
     fetch variables
  fin while
  ```
- Resueltos los puntos anteriores, el problema final es que terminas actualizando un valor `NULL` en `prestamo.saldo`, la tabla no lo permite y además es incorrecto que sea `NULL` esto se debe a la variable `@pagoMonto` no la llegas a inicializar nunca con esta consulta: `select @pagoMonto =  Sum(monto) from pagoPrestamo where pagoPrestamo.idCuenta = @idPrestamo` simplemente por que `@idPrestamo` no tiene ningún valor. Ademas, entiendo que la idea es actualizar el saldo del `prestamo` en función de los `pago` insertados. Con lo cual le veo otros dos problemas a tu trigger:

  1. No leas la tabla `pagoPrestamo` dentro del trigger, lo correcto sería acceder a la pseudo tabla `INSERTED` que representa los valores actualizados o insertados de la tabla del trigger. Existe además `DELETED` para leer los valores anteriores si los necesitaras. Además necesitas leer cada uno de los pagos, es decir el monto lo tiene que obtener en el mismo cursor que recorre cada uno de los pagos insertados.
  2. El otro problema es de lógica, esta consulta, esto: `set prestamo.saldo = prestamo.monto - @pagoMonto` solo funciona la primera vez, con un segundo pago ya no, lo correcto en todo caso es actuar sobre el `saldo`, es decir: **`set prestamo.saldo = prestamo.saldo - @pagoMonto`**

Resumiendo las observaciones tu cursor podría quedar así:

```
create trigger tr_pago_prestamo on pagoPrestamo
after insert
as
Begin

    declare @idCuenta int
    declare @pagoMonto decimal(13,2)

    declare logica cursor for 
    select  prestamo.idCuenta, PP.monto
        from prestamo 
        inner join INSERTED PP 
            on prestamo.idCuenta = pp.idCuenta

    open logica
    fetch next from logica into @idCuenta, @pagoMonto
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
    begin
        update prestamo set prestamo.saldo = ISNULL(prestamo.saldo,0) - ISNULL(@pagoMonto,0)
            where idCuenta = @idCuenta

        fetch next from logica into @idCuenta, @pagoMonto
    end
    close logica
    deallocate logica
end
```

Nota: eliminé también todas las declaraciones y consultas innecesarias para hacer más claro el código

Comment: Muchas gracias por la detallada respuesta, a funcionado maravillosamente, por lo que veo estaba dando muchas vueltas, muchas gracias nuevamente